# SNIX_CONNECT SNI_ERROR_35 after using dapper in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, dapper

I am using Dapper to connect with my Azure database. Everything works perfectly fine on the virtual device but after I deploy my app into a real device I got this error:
`SINX_CONNECTION (PROVIDER: SNI_PN7, ERROR:35 - SNI_ERROR_35)`
This appears when the app tries to receive something from the Azure database, via dapper.

My connection string (copied and pasted from azure portal):
`"Server=tcp:{database_server_name},1433;Initial Catalog={location_of_database};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={userid};Password={password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";`
It will be verry helpfull to get any clue what can cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it worked on a virtual device but xamarin does not support Dapper. Switching to SQLite solved a problem. In case of Stored procedures, I had to create external API :(